# Understanding of sine; opposite divide by hypotenuse

Tags: trigonometry

I am just trying to understand sine.

I know how it works, but I don't know why it works that way.

What exactly is result of $\frac{opposite(height)}{hypotenuse (radius)}$?

What is behind this *magic* operation?

*I know I can use it to find out an angle of triangle in sinusoide.*

I've read a lot of topics and I've seen a lot of videos about this, but I still don't get it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Trigonometric functions (and formulæ thereof) are best understood via the trigonometric circle (whence their other name of *circular functions*).

Comment: Just draw a right triangle and label the sides.  Your question "what exactly is the result..." is just a number, such as 0.3.  There is no "magic" operation... it is just a ratio of two lengths.

Comment: is my answer below helpful? If not, perhaps you can clarify what you mean when you ask "why it works" that way?

Comment: @Bernard This is Math SE, not TeX SE, just btw

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I've started to understand it by this.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Please, look at my question about ratio below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by "why it works" that way. The sine of some angle $\theta$ is defined as the ratio of the lengths of two sides of some arbitrary right triangle drawn about $\theta$ - specifically, we are taking the ratio of the lengths of the "opposite" side to the hypotenuse. It is simply a number that represents the ratio of the two side lengths.

Perhaps you are wondering why the sine of some fixed angle is always the same, despite the triangle, or why the sine of an angle on the unit circle is a sufficient representation of the sine all such angles... This works because all triangles with the same three angle measurements are similar. In other words, any triangle with the same three angles will have sides whose lengths are a constant multiple of any other triangle with the same three angles; hence, the ratios of the lengths between any two arbitrary sides will always remain the same between triangles.

Imagine we have an angle $\theta_1$. If we draw a right triangle about the angle $\theta_1$, then the third remaining angle is $\theta_2 = 180 - 90 - \theta_1$. Now, any right triangle drawn about the angle $\theta_1$, no matter what the side lengths are, will have the same three angle measurements and thus be similar. Therefore, the sine of the angle $\theta_1$ is invariant.